# Безопасность домашней папки home в Debian

Tags: debian, безопасность

Безопасно ли, если на FTP у пользователя в домашней папке home есть доступ к файлам: .profile, .bashrc и .bash_logout?

Comment: У пользователя в домашней папке есть и должен быть доступ ко все файлам. На то она и домашняя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Безопасно. А вот беспокоиться нужно о файлах `~/.gnupg/*` и `~/.ssh/*`